# type 3 grammar - regular expression

Tags: compiler-construction, regular-language

i've read a note that type 3 grammers can not have both these productions

```
A-> aB
A-> Ba
```

where A,B are non-terminals and a is a terminal

i know enough about type 3 but i can't understand the above

Comment: This is part of the **definition** of regular grammars, so there isn't much to understand about it.

Comment: so it's not wrong in general?

Comment: How would it be "wrong in general"?

Comment: Any grammar containing a rule of the form `A -> aB` and one of the form `A -> Ba` is by definition not a regular grammar.

Comment: @larsmans yes there is. you need to understand the notation, and the types of objects they denote. To grasp it you need to have a concept of what kind of usage is there for it. To be useful you have to know how to decide when do you want to use it. To see in its entirity, you need the reasoning behind the design choices of making this definition (aka history). There are many levels in understanding something like this, some of them maybe even untapped here. When someone is on "the other side of understanding" he often just sees another definition, but implicitly assumes these things existing.

Answer (score 1):

If you allow both of these productions to occur this would change the meaning of what type 3 is. You could write a grammar like the following:

```
A -> '(' B
B -> A ')'
A -> '1'
```

If you assume A to be the start non-terminal, your language would give you all words

```
((...((1))...))
```

where the number of parenthesis on either side is the same. This however is not a type 3 language (Informally, a correct parser needs to count, so it cannot be finite state).